# How can I create new Minecraft items in a Spigot plugin?

Tags: minecraft-modding

Is it possible to make a new custom item in a plugin so that in-hand 3D models and textures don't interfere with vanilla Minecraft items? How?

Comment: I believe spigot is server-side only so, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Minecraft client-server protocol doesn't support such things,

However, there's a workaround. You can assign different models to different damage values of objects. By using something, that normally can't get damaged (like for example a book) you can technically have new items. The same can't be done with blocks.